# Pulsar 220 F replaced with New suspension, still the problem persist

Tags: suspension

I have very good experience with my pulsar 220 past 9 years. Slowly, the ride becomes firmer. I could feel every bits and stones on my butt so, thinking of the age of the bike I changed the rear suspension with a brand new one(both). But still it so hard, i do not like to ride it like i used to. It should eat up tiny bumps nd minute broken patch of the road.

What should i do to fix it.

Comment: Are you using a different brand of tire? Or different pressure?

Comment: You write "I changed the rear suspension." What parts did you change? Did you replace the bushes at both ends of the suspension strut(s) ?

Comment: You may have worn out the seat after 9 years...

Comment: I am using the same brand of tire with the same air pressure, its old now 3 years maybe. @David i have changed the whole set, as in totally new. and yeah seats are fine I guess. Maybe changing the ball bearing & lube at the connector might help?

Answer (score -1):

Get your rear wheel aligned and weight balanced...your problem will be solved

Comment: Downvoted. Rear wheel alignment and balancing will have no effect on suspension harshness.